# Customizing Array of Query response

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, arraylist

I have a JSON response to be customized to our need

The response is like below which contains multiple arrays with data

but i want to sort out single category like MAIN and display all related stuff in a array with in its value

```js
[
  {
    "Main": [
      "Map View"
    ],
    "Reports": [
      "Sensor Data Report"
    ],
    "Configuration": [
      "Region Configuration"
    ],
    "Admin": [
      "Customer Management"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Main": [
      "Map View"
    ],
    "Reports": [
      "Sensor Data Report"
    ],
    "Configuration": [
      "Region Configuration"
    ],
    "Admin": [
      "Device Management"
    ]
  }
]
```

But I need to something like this

```js
{
  "Main": [
    "Dashboard",
    "Devices"
  ],
  "Reports": [
    "Alert Report",
    "MOnthly Reports"
  ],
  "Configuration": [
    "Region Configuration",
    "Device Management"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be, as your first multiple arrays with data contain a single item per entry, is to use 2 times a `foreach` and gather all the values for the same key.

As your example data contains duplicate values, you might use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arrays as $array)
    foreach ($array as $k => $v)
        array_key_exists($k, $result) ? $result[$k][] = $v[0] : $result[$k] = [$v[0]];

$result = array_map('array_unique', $result);

print_r($result);
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/BhRtO)

Result

```
Array
(
    [Main] => Array
        (
            [0] => Map View
        )

    [Reports] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sensor Data Report
        )

    [Configuration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Region Configuration
        )

    [Admin] => Array
        (
            [0] => Customer Management
            [1] => Device Management
        )

)
```

Comment: Meanwhile requirement got changed and i am able to do that, but thanks for the answer